# Why doesn't my linq to sql generated classes have OnCreated()

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, partials

I've been reading over the internet about a partial method that I can use called OnCreated() to run some logic against my Linq - SQL class while it is being created. How ever there is no partial class by that name for me to use. I'm sure I'm missing something small here.

Here is what I'm trying to call in the partial class

```
partial void OnCreated()
```

I'm getting the compile time error of

```
No defining declaration found for implementing declaration of partial method...
```

So I guess its not there and my question is why?

Thanks

Comment: Oh I might know... They are stored procs brought into LINQ - SQL

Comment: Did you check the generated code to see what was going on in there?  What version of VS are you using?

Comment: @Will - ya its not in the generated code. I think its cause its a sproc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only tables a view will have the Partial OnCreated

it works fine over here

the stored procedures are methods of the datacontext, they are not generating classes